# How does recursion work in this "flatten doubly linked list" code?

Tags: java, recursion

The problem is from leetcode #430 Flatten a Multilevel doubly Linked List.
So basically, each node has three fields: next, prev, and child. And the problem asks to flatten the given linked-list.

```
public Node flatten(Node head) {
    flattenHelper(head);
    return head;
}

public Node flattenHelper(Node head){
    if(head.next == null){
        //return if reach the tail
        System.out.println("returned " + head.val);
        return head;
    }
    if(head.child != null){
        Node prevNext = head.next;

        //link current node's next field to its child
        head.next = head.child;
        head.child = null;
        head.next.prev = head;

        //the tail of the child linked-list
        Node children = flatten(head.next);
        children.next = prevNext;
        prevNext.prev = children;
    }
    Node x = flatten(head.next);
    System.out.println("current Node value: " + head.val + " returned from the bottom: " + x.val);
    return x;
}
```

I know there are better ways to solve this problem, but why doesn't this code work?

From my understanding of recursion, the return value of the very bottom stack should get passed up to its caller stack through `Node x = flatten(head.next); return x;`, and eventually arrived at `Node children = flatten(head.next);` to get connected.

However, on the way up the stacks, `Node x = flatten(head.next); return x;` returns the node one stack below current node instead of the node returned from the very bottom stack.

[Example Test Case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NiluX.png)

[System.out.printlns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVs3w.png)

Thank you very much for helping out!

Comment: I don't know the full answer but the problem is in this part of your code `//the tail of the child linked-list
        Node children = flatten(head.next);
        children.next = prevNext;
        prevNext.prev = children;` run your code in leetcode without this and you're another step closer. The problem is in saving the old Node.next when adding a child to head.next

Comment: Within `flattenHelper()` change 2 `flatten(head.next)` statements to `flattenHelper(head.next)`. Your solution should work.